# Low R2 in statsmodels and High Accuracy/Precision in scikit

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, scikit-learn, data-science

I'm current in a Data Science course and one of my projects is creating a model to predict employee attrition.

I have a mock data set that I'm using and I've already set up my X and y's.

I ran 4 models.  The first was running a logistic regression in statsmodels.  The output of that was a Pseudo Rsquared of 0.142, so pretty low.

However, the next 3 models I ran in scikit learn (logistic regression, k nearest neighbor and decision tree).  In these models, I split up the X and y's into train and test sets.  For each, I ran accuracy and precision scores and they are all above 75%.  Also, I ran cross validation scores on each model and still above 75% on each.

My question is, how is it possible that I get high scores on my scikit learn models and such a low R2 on the statsmodel run?

Can this situation happen?  and if so, how can it be explained?  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question with sufficient and specific information such as the code attempted to solve the problem and error message, etc.

Comment: Maybe, i misunderstood you, but R2 is a measure of ERROR, so, when error is low, the score, correspondingly high. Everything seems OKay to mee

Comment: This is very unclear. The problem you are solving: is it regression or classification? You say you measured `R2`, it seems that its regression then. But then you say you calculate accuracy and precision?? Accuracy and precision are used for classification, not regression. Can you post the code for both libraries and also some data.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer because I never compared them in any examples.

(This looks more like a statistics than a programming question stats.stackexchange ?).

Essentially, both measures are somewhat but not directly related, pseudo-rsquare in the definition used in statsmodels compares the loglikelihood of the full model with the loglikelihood of a model with only a constant. The measure is on the scale of a loglikelihood ratio and it shows relative improvement compared to the constant-only reference model.

Accuracy and precision directly measure predictive performance, which uses a different scale and is an absolute measure that does not compare to a reference model.
For example, you could check how much do the predictive measures improve compared to a constant-only model.

Another difference in the specific measures is that accuracy and precision use thresholding and discretize the prediction. In contrast, the loglikelihood is based on the probabilities.
For example, if the threshold is 0.5. then an observation with a probability of 0.500001 or 0.49999 might be the correct prediction in either case, but the probabilities are far away from 1 and 0.